# how to stop losing focus when something is printed out to eclipse Console View?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm suffering from an annoying feature in Eclipse 4+.

I start a program which will generate some output to the Console view periodically,Then i continue editing the source code in Java Editor,when the output comes out,I lost focus in the Java Editor.This would'nt happend in Eclipse 3.7.

how to avoid this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Top right of the console view there there are two icons indicate "Show Console when Standard Out changes" and "Show Console when Standard Error changes",I see they are checked,when i uncheck them, the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

One of the icons at the top right of the console should do the trick.

Comment: This isn't an answer.